# Adjusting transparency for all but some series in chart

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on an old excel file which I'm using to plot laboratory tests. I am now trying to loop through the chart series in order to make some of the test series to stand out. I want to do this by adjusting increasing the transparency of the other series in the graph.

When running the code below it will instead turn fill and border of the markers off.
Any ideas to why this might be happening and how to solve it?
I have done similar loops through charts before but the transparency seems to do weird things

Best regards
Robin

Example of chart before running code:

[image: Example of chart before running code]

Example of chart after running the code:

[image: Example of chart after running the code]

```
Sub invisible()
Dim i As Integer
Dim f As String
Dim MyValue As String

If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Choose a graph"
    Exit Sub
End If

MyValue = InputBox("Adjust transparency (0-100)", "default", 0)

i = 1
For Each Series In ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection
    f = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name
    
    If f Like "*_DS" Then
        With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i)
            .Format.Fill.Transparency = 0
            .Format.Line.Transparency = 0
        End With
    Else
        With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i)
            .Format.Fill.Transparency = MyValue / 100
            .Format.Line.Transparency = MyValue / 100
        End With
    End If
i = i + 1
Next

End Sub
```